# Too many clauses?

Tags: php, while-loop

I've written quite a messy function which returns 3 fields based on constraints of it matching with other fields. It has 3 results based on the final result it will return result 2.

```
public function ListRoomTotals($room, $date, $dateTo = null) {

    // If dateTo hasn't been set, make it now

    if(!isset($dateTo) or $dateTo == "") {

        $dateTo = $date;

    }

    // Return an array with each bundle number and the quantity for each day

    $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `scanners` WHERE `Scanner` IN (";

        foreach($scanner as $x) {

            $sql .= $x . ",";

        }

    $sql .= "0)

            AND `Date` BETWEEN '" . $date . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "'

            GROUP BY `KordNo`, `BundleNumber`;";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $sql = "SELECT `BundleReference`, `QtyIssued`, `WorksOrder`,

                FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $row['KordNo'] . "'

                AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $row['BundleNumber'] . "';";

        $result2 = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $sql = "SELECT `ArchiveBundle`.`QtyIssued`, `ArchiveBundle`.`WorksOrder`,

                        `ArchiveBundle`.`Colour`, `ArchiveBundle`.`Size`

                FROM `ArchiveBundle`

                WHERE `ArchiveBundle`.`KordNo` = '" . $x['KordNo'] . "' AND

                  `ArchiveBundle`.`BundleNumber` = '" . $x['BundleNumber'] . "';";

        $result3 = mysql_query($sql);
                        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result3);   


           // Now we need to query what the product group is

        $sql = "SELECT `Stock`.`ProductGroup`

            FROM `Stock`, `TWOrder`

            WHERE `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber` = '" . $row[1] . "' AND

                `TWOrder`.`Colour` = '" . $row[2] . "' AND

                `TWOrder`.`Size` = '" . $row[3] . "' AND

                `Stock`.`ProductCode` = `TWOrder`.`Product`;";



        $result4 = mysql_query($sql);

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result4);

        if(in_array($row2[0], array(50, 100, 150, 300 , 350 , 925 ,930, 940)))

        {


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

            if($row[0] != "") {

                $final[] = $row;

            } else {

                $final[] = array("Can't find bundle number", "N/A");

            }

        }

    }

    return $final;

   }
```

I have a for loop using the function on a page like below.

```
 $result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $_GET['date']);

            $total = 0;

            foreach($result as $x) {

                $content .= "<tr>

                    <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>

                    <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>

                </tr>";
                                    $total += $x[1];

            }

            $weeklyTotal += $total;

            $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>" . $total . "                    </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>" .      number_format($total/12,2) . "</td></tr></table>

        </td>
```

I know its probably very badly written as it is the main reason nothing is returned correctly. Does anyone have any advise to split it up perhaps. I'm pretty basic at php so my understanding of it is poor. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick hint: Remove unnecessary blank lines from your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Too many blank lines and too much indentation.

Comment: @BoltClock I suspect those blank line have come from copy/pasting between something that uses `\r\n` and something that doesn't...

Comment: @DaveRandom: What do you mean?

Comment: @BoltClock If you use an editor in Windows that uses `\r\n` as EOL, then copy/paste into something that just uses `\r` or `\n`, some (but not all) will interpret the `\r\n` sequence as two new lines, and you end up with extra line breaks in the display - then when you save the file, the editor uses it's own line breaks, and you end up with extra line breaks in the file. This probably happened some time in the distant past (not when pasting code here) but that's probably where they came from.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Wow. That's a pretty weird bug if you ask me.

Comment: The first code sample is missing two `}`'s at the end. I have only found this out when I spaced the code consistently. This means that you are calling `return` in the first iteration of the outer `while` loop. When you say `nothing is returned correctly`, do you mean that you only get the first result you expect? If not, what do you expect, and what do you get? Does you version of the function even parse?

Comment: @BoltClock I know it is v. annoying - I can't remember where I came across it, but I have definitely come across it (might have been with Notepad and a very old version of EditPadPro)

Comment: I mean nothing is returned. I've taken a bit of advise of what ive seen from posts and decided to komodo as it seems to be better than gedit which is what i copied and pasted from.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of small changes if your code and removed most of the unwanted white-space. My advice would be to break the function ListRoomTotals into smaller functions. For example getScanners could be moved into it's own function. So instead of nesting the function based on results you break out each subtask into a smaller function. Also in your query you have SELECT *. This is a performance issue as well, if you only need two or three fields. You could refactor you're queries as well.

```
public function ListRoomTotals($room, $date, $dateTo = null) {
    // If dateTo hasn't been set, make it now
    if(!isset($dateTo) || $dateTo == "") { //<-- Replaced or with ||
        $dateTo = $date;
    }

    // Return an array with each bundle number and the quantity for each day
    $scanner = $this->GetScannerNumber($room);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `scanners` WHERE `Scanner` IN (".implode(',', $scanner);

    // replace foreach loop with implode
    //foreach($scanner as $x) {
    //  $sql .= $x . ",";
    //}

    $sql .= "0)
    AND `Date` BETWEEN '" . $date . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "'
    GROUP BY `KordNo`, `BundleNumber`;";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sql = "SELECT `BundleReference`, `QtyIssued`, `WorksOrder`,
        FROM `ArchiveBundle`
        WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $row['KordNo'] . "'
        AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $row['BundleNumber'] . "';";

        $result2 = mysql_query($sql);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {     
            $sql = "SELECT `ArchiveBundle`.`QtyIssued`, `ArchiveBundle`.`WorksOrder`,
            `ArchiveBundle`.`Colour`, `ArchiveBundle`.`Size`
            FROM `ArchiveBundle`
            WHERE `ArchiveBundle`.`KordNo` = '" . $x['KordNo'] . "' AND
            `ArchiveBundle`.`BundleNumber` = '" . $x['BundleNumber'] . "';";

            $result3 = mysql_query($sql);
            $row     = mysql_fetch_row($result3);

            // Now we need to query what the product group is
            $sql = "SELECT `Stock`.`ProductGroup`
            FROM `Stock`, `TWOrder`
            WHERE `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber` = '" . $row[1] . "' AND
            `TWOrder`.`Colour` = '" . $row[2] . "' AND
            `TWOrder`.`Size` = '" . $row[3] . "' AND
            `Stock`.`ProductCode` = `TWOrder`.`Product`;";

            $result4 = mysql_query($sql);
            $row2    = mysql_fetch_row($result4);

            if(in_array($row2[0], array(50, 100, 150, 300 , 350 , 925 ,930, 940))) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    if($row[0] != "") {
                        $final[] = $row;
                    } else {
                        $final[] = array("Can't find bundle number", "N/A");
                    }
                }
            }
            return $final;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
$result = $scanner->ListRoomTotals($_GET['room'], $_GET['date']);
    $total = 0;

    foreach($result as $x) {
        $content .= "<tr>
            <td>" . $x[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $x[1] . "</td>
        </tr>";
        $total += $x[1];
    }
    $weeklyTotal += $total;
    $content .= "<tr><td>Total Pairage:</td><td>".$total."                    </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Total Dozens:</td><td>".number_format($total/12,2)."</td></tr></table>
</td>"; //<-- adding the closing double quote
```

UPDATE:

Not sure where there are being defined:

```
$x['KordNo']
$x['BundleNumber']
```

Did you mean

```
$row['KordNo']
$row['BundleNumber']
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your code makes it very difficult to see what's going on.

Once cleaned up, it seems like you are doing a series of SQL queries, each of which depends on the previous one. It would make much more sense to perform a single query using JOINs, to access the data that you want.

In addition, you make two queries

```
 $sql = "SELECT `BundleReference`, `QtyIssued`, `WorksOrder`,
         FROM `ArchiveBundle`
         WHERE `KordNo` = '" . $row['KordNo'] . "'
           AND `BundleNumber` = '" . $row['BundleNumber'] . "';";
```

and

```
 $sql = "SELECT `ArchiveBundle`.`QtyIssued`, `ArchiveBundle`.`WorksOrder`,
                `ArchiveBundle`.`Colour`, `ArchiveBundle`.`Size`
         FROM `ArchiveBundle`
         WHERE `ArchiveBundle`.`KordNo` = '" . $x['KordNo'] . "' 
           AND `ArchiveBundle`.`BundleNumber` = '" . $x['BundleNumber'] . "';";
```

which seem redundant.

Also, you're referring to `$x` here, but `$x` was simply an index variable used to generate a comma-separated list of scanners; I doubt that's what you meant.

My advice is this: figure out what information you're trying to pull from the DB, work out the correct SQL for this data request and then go from there.

From your code, I *think* the query you want is:

```
   SELECT `scanners`.*, ArchiveBundle`.`QtyIssued`, `Stock`.`ProductGroup`
    FROM `Stock` INNER JOIN `TWOrder` ON 
                    `Stock`.`ProductCode` = `TWOrder`.`Product`
                 INNER JOIN `ArchiveBundle` ON
                    `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber` = `ArchiveBundle`.`WorksOrder` AND
                    `TWOrder`.`Colour` = `ArchiveBundle`.`Colour` AND
                    `TWOrder`.`Size` = `ArchiveBundle`.`Size`
                 INNER JOIN `scanners` ON
                    `ArchiveBundle`.`KordNo` = `scanners`.`KordNo` AND 
                    `ArchiveBundle`.`BundleNumber` = `scanners`.`BundleNumber`
    WHERE `scanners`.`Scanners` IN (?...?)";
```